# sql server, local variable, declare table, set to null

Tags: sql-server, variables, null

I want to know if its possible to set a declare variable (as table), to null.

like :

```
DECLARE @TABLE1 AS TABLE (COL1 INT)
SET @TABLE1 = NULL
```

I searche a way to know if I already try to insert data into my variable

Comment: It's a little hard to tell what the question is since you have scattered various clarifications through comments on the answers.  Perhaps you could update the question with all of the details.  If your data will never include `NULL` then you could insert a `NULL` in the table as a placeholder to indicate that you have visited the table, but had zero rows to insert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To complete your question about if you've added rows or not you can do:

```
insert into @TABLE1 (COL1) VALUES ([someYourData])

if @@ROWCOUNT > 0
   -- row addeded
ELSE
   -- nothing added
```

or you can check the value of `@@ROWCOUNT` to know how many rows has been added so:

```
insert into @TABLE1 (COL1) VALUES ([someYourData])
print @@ROWCOUNT
```

For what i know `@TABLE1` have a `local scope` so when the Store Procedure is end, this variable will be deleted

and as GSerg said you have many whays to check it as:

```
if exists (select * from @TABLE1)
BEGIN
   --  do something
END
```

or

```
if (select count(@@rowcount) from @TABLE1) > 0
BEGIN
   --  do something
END
```

or

```
if (select count(*) from @TABLE1) > 0
BEGIN
   --  do something
END
```

Comment: yeah, but every way give the number of row and not if I try to put X rows (can be 0)

Comment: @forX i've update the answer to give you more information, hope it help

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't.

If you need to remember whether you have tried to insert data into a @table, use a separate `bit` variable as a flag.

If you need to know whether your @table contains any rows, use

```
if exists (select * from @table1)
begin
    ...
end;
```

Comment: did the select * from @table1 will be execute? I mean, I dont care if theres only a few data into table1. But if I have thousands lines, I lost performance.

Comment: I knew for the bit, I already start to use that, but that double my variables. I was hoping for something something else. But if you said that I cant.

Comment: `exists` does not select, it checks existance. Because there is no `where` clause, checking existance translates to checking if there is at least one row on the table.

Comment: so I cant use it for checking if I already TRY to insert because, it will said false if its empty. but sometimes I get no data, and its good. I need to know if I try to do insert into, and not if theres something inside. So I will probably need a bit.